# Silverstripe - two form submissions on one controller

Tags: forms, controller, silverstripe

I am trying to submit two forms to their respective databases on the same controller with one submit button.

Using onAfterWrite I need to submit the first form grab its ID and pass it to the second form, then it submits the second form and then redirects to success.

Is this even possible or is it supposed to be done another way?

```
public static function FormAction1($data, $form) {

 $form->sessionMessage('Update successful', 'success');
 $submission = Form1::get()->byID($data["ID"]);  
 $form->saveInto($submission);
 $submission->write();
 return Controller::curr()->redirectBack();

public static function FormAction2($data, $form) {

 $form->sessionMessage('Update successful', 'success');
 $submission = Form2::get()->byID($data["ID"]);  
 $form->saveInto($submission);
 $submission->write();
 return Controller::curr()->redirectBack();
```

Comment: Is there any reason you need two forms? Can't you just do the same with a single form?

Comment: They are currently on 2 separate pages but I want them both on 1 page to save the user an extra click. They are different entities so won't work having them in the same table. Will need to be separate.

Comment: But your action handlers both take the same data as input, right? Or how should the second form-data be populated if the user doesn't have a chance to fill in the content? Maybe you should clarify your question…

Answer (score 3):

Generally I would suggest structuring your code differently to achieve this.

If you have three form actions, and one of them performs the other two actions, then you could instead structure it as three form actions that call different methods depending on their requirements. For example, let's say you want three actions - 'Save', 'Notify users', and 'Save & Notify users'. I would structure this like so:

```
class Page_Controller extends ContentController {
    public function Form() {
        $actions = new ArrayList([
            new FormAction('save', 'Save'),
            new FormAction('notify', 'Notify users'),
            new FormAction('saveandnotify', 'Save & Notify users')
        ]);

        return new Form($this, 'Form', $fields, $actions);
    }

    public function save($data, Form $form) {
        if($this->doSave($data, $form)) {
            $form->sessionMessage('Save successful', 'good');
        } else {
            $form->sessionMessage('Failed to save', 'bad');
        }

        return $this->redirectBack();
    }

    public function notify($data, Form $form) {
        if($this->doNotify($data, $form)) {
            $form->sessionMessage('Notified users successfully', 'good');
        } else {
            $form->sessionMessage('Failed to notify users', 'bad');
        }

        return $this->redirectBack();
    }

    public function saveandnotify($data, Form $form) {
        // First, attempt save
        if($this->doSave($data, $form)) {
            // Successful, so now notify users
            if($this->doNotify($data, $form)) {
                $form->sessionMessage('Saved and notified users', 'good');
            } else {
                $form->sessionMessage('Saved, but unable to notify users', 'bad');
            }
        } else {
            $form->sessionMessage('Unable to save or notify users', 'bad');
        }

        return $this->redirectBack();
    }

    /**
     * Saves data from a form submission.
     * @return bool true if save was successful, false if it failed
     */
    public function doSave($data, Form $form) {
        // ... your code here ...
    }

    /**
     * Notify users based on a form submission.
     * @return bool true if notification was successful, false if it failed
     */
    public function doNotify($data, Form $form) {
        // ... your code here ...
    }
}
```

This separates concerns between form action handling and the actual business logic, which also allows you to more easily test the business logic without needing to perform full form submissions (just create a `Form` object, set values and then run your tests).

It also allows you to move the business logic into separate classes once it inevitably becomes too complicated for a single Page controller to handle. At this point I generally look at 'service' objects that provides various business functionality as separate decoupled classes.

edit: I also see that you have these forms on two separate classes at the moment. I assume this is either two separate `Form` classes or two different page types? In that case, having a service class would help - it means you can refer to the same logic (`doSave` and `doNotify` in my case) across all page types and know you'll get the same logic each time.

HTH!